# Object Web, Visit Classes that have static methods

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

what is the way in ASM visitors to figure out the class type of the class containing a static method.

My code looks like

```java
    public static class A {
        public void a() {
            B.b();
        }
    }

    public static class B {
        public static void b() {
        }
    }
```

So I want when visiting class `A` to be noticed that class `B`  is being used

Comment: print a trace. Basically, like a stacktrace.

Comment: Implement a `ClassVisitor` to visit `A` and within [`visitMethod`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitMethod-int-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-), check whether it’s `a()`, then return a `MethodVisitor` whose [`visitMethodInsn`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitMethodInsn-int-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-) you’ve overwritten. When `opcode` is [`INVOKESTATIC`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes.html#INVOKESTATIC), you known, you’re there.

Comment: yes, that works, then class comes in the owner parameter that is what I was looking for. Thx